# bash sed/awk: replace string from a file searching in another file

Tags: bash, awk

i have a question about search and replacement on Debian. I have two files. One with:

```
a:b
c:d
e:f
```

and the other with:

```
 e
 c
 a`
```

In the second file I want to replace `a` with `b`, `c` with `d`, `e` with `f`.
How can I do this?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400217/replace-a-field-with-values-specified-in-another-file

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F: 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {for (i in a)sub(i, a[i]);print}' file1 file2
 f
 d
 b
```

#### How it works

- `-F:`

  This tells `awk` to split fields on the colon.
- `FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}`

  While reading the first file, this tells `awk` to create a dictionary `a` of the translations that we want to do.
- `for (i in a)sub(i, a[i])`

  While reading the second file file, this tells `awk` to substitute in for every entry that we have stored in our dictionary `a`.
- `print`

  After we have made the substitutions, this tells `awk` to print the line.

#### Replacing file2

To replace `file2` with the new version:

```
awk -F: 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {for (i in a)sub(i, a[i]);print}' file1 file2 >tmp && mv tmp file2
```

With very recent versions of `awk`, there is a shortcut option for this: `-i inplace`.  Beneath the surface, though, what this option does is exactly what the command above does.

Comment: thanks a lots ! This works it print result on my console. but it doesn't replace in file2. how i do that

Comment: @maungoldman A method to replace file2 is included in the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more complicated:

```
sed -f <(sed 's!\(.*\):\(.*\)!s/\1/\2/!' file1) file2
```

- `sed 's!\(.*\):\(.*\)!s/\1/\2/!' file1` reads the first file and outputs:

  ```
  s/a/b/
  s/c/d/
  s/e/f/
  ```
- `<(the_above)` runs the above command
  with output to a temporary file.
- `sed -f <(…) file2` runs `sed` on `file2` using that temporary file as an input (script) file.

To send the output back into `file2`, add a `-i` option:

```
sed -i -f <(sed 's!\(.*\):\(.*\)!s/\1/\2/!' file1) file2
```